# Do Melee/Missile Damage Reduction Apply to Followers?

Tags: diablo-iii

Does the secondary affix "Reduces Damage from [Melee|Ranged] Attacks by [n]%" work on Followers (Enchantress, Templar, and Scoundrel)?

Clarification: I am not asking if I equip this to my Hero, would it affect my Follower. I am asking if equipping a Follower with an item bearing this affix will actually work. The reason why I ask is that, Damage Reduction does not appear on the Follower's Detail Sheet.

Comment: I'm not sure, but reading your question, are you asking if having the affix on an item equipped by the follower applies to the follower?  Or are you asking if having the affix on an item equipped by your character applies to the follower?  Or are you asking if equipping an item with the affix on your follower will help your character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you mean: Does equipping the affix on yourself apply to your followers. (Obviously equipping it on them would work)

The answer is no, it only applies to the person or follower that currently has the equipment on them.

If you equip the item on a follower, it applies to them. You just don't see it because it counts as a hidden stat.

Comment: My apologies. I meant that if this affix does apply to Followers since it is not shown in the Follower's details sheet.

Comment: Yes it applies to your followers if they have it equipped on them. For whatever reason the followers dont have an in depth details sheet like characters do.

Comment: It still counts, but considers as a hidden stat.